# UITextfield not working as subview to UISearchBar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, ios7, uisearchbar

This code worked perfectly fine in iOS 6 but in iOS 7 the textfield is gray in the navigationBar, and not clickable? See the difference in this picture

[image]

What may be wrong ? I am not aware of what they have changed exactly in iOS 7 and not sure where to start looking for solving this problem...

/Regards

```
UITextField *sbTextField = (UITextField *)[searchBar.subviews lastObject];
[sbTextField removeFromSuperview];

CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
rect.size.height = 32;
rect.size.width = 210;
sbTextField.frame = rect;
 // [sbTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation]; Not working in iOS7
 // [sbTextField setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"HintSearchExercise", nil)]; Not working in iOS 7

[sbTextField setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
[searchBar removeFromSuperview];

UIBarButtonItem *searchBarNavigationItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sbTextField];

[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:searchBarNavigationItem];
```

Comment: Why are you removing the text field from the search bar? Messing with the private subview structure of a standard UI control is never a good approach to solving a problem.

Comment: I deleted the code where I romved the searchBar fromSuperview and the result is still messy: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1056r7q&s=5#.UkIjzpKpWrg :/

Comment: You need to show the code for setting up the colors and appearance. You should also remove all code that changes any of the layout of the textfield. Use the provided `UISearchBar` API to make any adjustments you need. Don't mess with the private subviews.

Answer (score 3):

in ios7 `[searchBar.subviews lastObject]` is *not* the text field but instead a `UIView` instance that acts as an additional container around the controls.

having the same problem with [cocktailicious](http://www.cocktailiciousapp.com), i plan to use the following category on `UISearchBar`:

```
@interface UISearchBar (Workarounds)
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation UISearchBar (Workarounds)
- (UITextField *)textField
{
    for (UIView *view in [self subcontrols]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            return (UITextField *)view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSArray *)subcontrols
{
    return self.subviews.count == 1 ? [self.subviews.firstObject subviews] : self.subviews;
}
@end
```

the `- subcontrols` method does the trick here.

Comment: just wanted to add I had the same problem in Swift with iOS 8.2 and with your comment I was able to fix it

Comment: Likewise! Very helpful.