# Change the frame size of UISearchBar TextField?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisearchbar

I am unable to set frame of UISearchBarTextField.... Should I create my own Search Bar or Is there a way to do the above?

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UISearchBarTextField.h

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556814/changing-the-size-of-the-uisearchbar-textfield look this

Comment: at least share some codes,what you tried?

Comment: UITextField *txfSearchField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[txfSearchField setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 200, 30)];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993773/uitextfield-not-working-as-subview-to-uisearchbar-in-ios-7 .... try this link for getting uitextfield of search bar..

Comment: I will look into those links

Answer (score 2):

in iOS 7 to access Text Field you have to reiterate on level more. Change your code like this

```
for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subViews){
    for (UIView *2ndLeveSubView in subView.subViews){
    if ([2ndLeveSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)2ndLeveSubView;

            break;
        }
    }
   }
```

But best way to clear backgournd of UISearchBar and setting searchbar icon in text field is:

```
[searchBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] ];//if you want to remove background of uisearchbar
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"search_icon.png"];
[searchBar setImage:image forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -5):

Have you try this.

```
 [searchBarObj setFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 320 - 44, 43)];
```

Comment: I am unable to increase it's preset size 50x33

Comment: i am not understand what exactly you want. provide some more description.